# Absolute div moves on parent being assigned relative position

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div that is position:absolute. The container within has vertically centered text. This spans across the whole width of the parent div.

However when I place a container div around the vertically centered text set at 50% the parent div, it ignores this and continues to span 100% across the top parent div.

I have tried setting the new container to relative positioning but this just forces it to disappear. Altering the width of the div .quote-center to 50% seems to achieve the correct width, but this wouldn't be suitable as it doesn't allow me to manipulate each box how I wish when the layout changes responsively.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbGZOL

```css
.brick {
  position: absolute;
}
.size42-insta {
  width: 640px;
  height: 320px;
}
.red {
  background-color: #da4a44;
}
.instagram {} .instagram-image {
  width: 50%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.instagram-quote {
  width: 50%;
}
.quote-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
}
.quote-center {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.quote-vcenter {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
.quote {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "omnes-pro", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="brick size42-insta red">
  <div class="instagram">
    <div class="instagram-image">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/87F6Nvc.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="instagram-quote">
      <div class="quote-content">
        <div class="quote-center">
          <span class="quote-vcenter">
                <div class="social-title">INSTAGRAM</div>
                <div class="twitter-tweet">“Sed bibendum malesuada sapien, vestibulum porta tortor ultrices"
                </div>
                <div class="twitter-date">19 hours ago
                </div>
                <div class="icon-stream twitter-stream"><a href="http://twitter.com/">a</a></div>
              </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: sorry, what do you want where? this is pretty hard to understand at present.

Comment: I want the text to be contained within the div. If you look at the running version. The text should be inside the red side of the div.

Comment: @databot you should accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simplify and restructure the columns completely, but to fix the issue you have right now (described in the comments on your question), you need to change the positioning of `.quote-content`, and add a width value:

```
.quote-content {
  right:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

You'll need to remove `left:0` as well. So the styles would be:

```
.quote-content {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:100;
}
```

EDIT:

To vertically align the absolutely positioned div (with what you have right now), you can use auto margin, as long as you define top, right, bottom and left values as well:

```
.quote-content {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto 0 auto auto;
  width:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:100;
  bottom:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj88q5tu/1/show)

[JSfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/jj88q5tu/1/)

Comment: This seems to just place the div outside the parent. 
I'm unsure if I can simplify it as I require it to be vertically centered.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was wondering though is this truly contained within this div? as I need to shift it around when moving responsively.

Comment: It will be contained in the parent div, but to be safe you could declare relative positioning to the parent element. You'll need to adjust styles with media queries for better responsive-ness.

Answer (score 1):

On .quote-content add a width of 50% and remove the left: 0;
If you want the width to be smaller remember to add to the right: 0;
So if you would make it 40% width you need to add 5% to the right

40% plus 5% right is 45% that leaves 5% for left totalling 50% again.

```
.quote-content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 40%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgMPqr